# Объединение данных из списков более быстрым способом

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть 3 класса. Структура простая:

```
//Класс наклеек
class Nakleika()
{
    String id;
    String name;
    //get и set методы
} 

//Класс пользователя (имеет наклейки)
class Person() 
{
    String name;
    ArrayList<Nakleika> nakleikalist;
    //get и set методы
}

//Конечный класс
class NakleikaPerson()
{
    Nakleika nakleika;
    ArrayList<Person> personList;
    //get и set методы
}
```

И есть два списка: `ArrayList<Nakleika> nakleikalist` и `ArrayList<Person> personList`.

Из этих двух списков нужно создать `ArrayList<NakleikaPerson>`.

Я это всё могу спокойно реализовать через циклы `for`. И это будет работающим решением. Но дело в том, что `ArrayList<Nakleika> nakleikalist` имеет больше 500 элементов, `ArrayList<Person> personList` - более 100 (причем в нем еще может быть более 500 наклеек).

Если я начну использовать циклы, это может выйти до 100*500*500 = 25000000 итераций. А это слишком ресурсоемко и долго по времени.

Как это можно ускорить? Есть, например, такая идея: при нахождение нужной наклейки у пользователя удалять её у него (чтобы уменьшить количество итераций). Но мне кажется, что есть подходы для более быстрой обработки.

Код с циклами:

```
ArrayList<NakleikaPerson> nakleikaPerson = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nakleikalist.size(); i++)
{
    NakleikaPerson nakleikaPers = new NakleikaPerson();
    for (int j = 0; j < personList.size(); j++)
    {
        for (int q = 0; q < personList.get(j).getNakleikalist.size(); q++)
        {
            if (nakleikalist.get(i).getId == personList.get(j).getNakleikalist.get(q).getId)
            {
                nakleikaPers.addPerson(personList.get(j).getPerson());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    nakleikaPerson.add(nakleikaPers);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть `N` - это количество элементов в глобальном `nakleikalist`, а также, для упрощения расчетов, в `nakleikalist` внутри `Person`.
`M` - количество элементов в глобальном `personList`.

Результатом должен быть такой список:

```
ArrayList<NakleikaPerson> nakleikaPersons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Добавление в `ArrayList`, а также добавление и получение из `HashMap` можно считать за `O(1)`.

Решение "в лоб":

```
for (Nakleika nakleika : nakleikaList)
{
    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person person : personList)
    {
        if (person.nakleikalist.contains(nakleika))
        {
            persons.add(person);
        }
    }
    nakleikaPersons.add(new NakleikaPerson(nakleika, persons));
}
```

Сложность алгоритма выходит `O(N * M * N)` (внешний `for` * внутренний `for` * `contains`).

---

Если заранее отсортировать `nakleikalist` (для нужно "уметь" сравнивать объекты `Nakleika`) у каждого `Person` (за `O(M * N * log(N)`), то вместо метода `contains` можно будет воспользоваться бинарным поиском (`O(N * M * log(N)`), что в итоге даст сложность `O(N * M * log(N))`. Это уже лучше.

---

Если же пары "наклейка - список людей" сохранить в `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<Nakleika, ArrayList<Person>> nakleikaToPersons = new HashMap<>();
for (Person person : personList)
{
    for (Nakleika nakleika : person.nakleikalist)
    {
        nakleikaToPersons.putIfAbsent(nakleika, new ArrayList<>());
        nakleikaToPersons.get(nakleika).add(person);
    }
}
for (Nakleika nakleika : nakleikaList)
{
    ArrayList<Person> persons = nakleikaToPersons.get(nakleika);
    nakleikaPersons.add(new NakleikaPerson(nakleika, persons));
}
```

То сложность уменьшится до `O(N * M)` (внешний `for` * внутренний `for`).

---

При использовании Java 7 вместо

```
nakleikaToPersons.putIfAbsent(nakleika, new ArrayList<>());
```

можно использовать

```
if (!nakleikaToPersons.containsKey(nakleika))
{
    nakleikaToPersons.put(nakleika, new ArrayList<Person>());
}
```

Comment: сейчас попробую ваш способ))

Comment: Пока возникла ошибка. Ищу её решения
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method putIfAbsent(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Ljava/util/HashMap; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.HashMap' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

Comment: @Ewrei_228 добавил в конец ответа поправку для Java 7.

Comment: спасибо большое))